# Two trigonometrical answers for same exercise. Which is the right one?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to resolve a trigonometrical exercise. I have two ways to resolve it and I receive two different answers. If you could help explain me why one way is a wrong way to resolve it (without doing reference to the trigonometric functions please).

Using *double-angle formulas* one way is:
\begin{align}
\cos(2x) = \cos^2x \\
\ 2\cos^2x -1 = \cos^2x \\
\ \cos^2x - 1 = 0 \\
\ \cos^2x = 1 \\
\ x = 360^\circ k
\end{align}
The second way is:
\begin{align}
\cos(2x) = \cos^2x \\
\ \cos^2x - \sin^2x = \cos^2x \\
\ -\sin^2x = 0 \\
\ \sin^2x = 0\\
\ x = 180^\circ k
\end{align}
As you see there are two answers, I know that the last one is the right one but don't know why (please don't do reference to the graphs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first calculations, the numbers $x = 360^\circ k$ only yield the solution to the equation $\cos(x) = 1$. However, the equation $\cos^2(x) = 1$ has other solutions, namely the $x$ that satisfy $\cos(x) = -1$. Therefore in the first case you also have $x = 360^\circ k + 180^\circ$ as a solution, therefore all solutions have the form $x = 180^\circ k$.

Answer (score 4):

The first one should have $\cos x=\pm 1\Rightarrow x=n.180$

Answer (score 0):

Technically the second way is correct. But this is only true because you accidentally messed up the solution to the equation $\cos^2({x}) = 1$. In fact, this equation is only solved when $x=180^\circ k$.

Therefore, both $methods$ are correct. But only one solution is correct: $x=180^\circ k$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good point. I've fixed it now.